# Solar Li-Po battery charger with MPPT algorithm

Tags: mppt, lithium-polymer, solar-charge-controller

I'm new here but I have read a lot of topics here about my question. I am designing a solar battery charger with MPPT algorithm but I don't know if I am doing it well.

First of all my specs are here:

**Solar Panel:**

- 10 W peak power
- Maximum Power Current: I<sub>MP</sub> = 0.57 A
- Maximum Power Voltage: V<sub>MP</sub> = 17.49 V
- Short Circuit Current: I<sub>SC</sub> = 0.61 A
- Open Circuit Voltage: V<sub>OC</sub> = 21.67 V

**Battery:**

- One cell Lithium-Polymer
- Nominal Voltage: 3.7 V
- Capacity: 1700 mAh (max 1C)

This is my actual schematic:

[image: Schematic]

The µC is working from 3.3 V.

Secondly:

I've designed a buck converter with the following values:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f5Pi82.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The problem is controlling the MOSFET with PWM in full-closed and full-opened states. Should I use a gate driver IC or another method?

Thereafter:

When the night comes, or the PV doesn't generate enough power, I have to stop the charging and MPPT. How do I know that the sun gives enough power to start MPPT, without starting it? (I was thinking about measuring the I<sub>SC</sub> to know the possible I<sub>MPP</sub>).

Finally:

- Do I have to use a charger IC to protect the battery form bad charging behavior?
- What do you think about the MP2615 charger? Is it good in this case?

I hope you can help.

Comment: 10 W into a single cell will not play nicely. Do you have other loads in the system or are you not going to run full current?

Comment: No.
It is just a standalone charger.
If I'm right, I would like to make the system work on a lower power (not use the whole 10 W) when the irradiance is high. I would use the MPP on cloudy days (when irradiance is lower).
I know it is energy wasting but when I have started this project, I did not choose the parts very well so I work with my current parts :D

Comment: Well, you sort of have to or your battery will explode :-)

Comment: What is your opinion?
Would this setup work (without explode anything)?

Comment: It you implement a suitable constant current limit in your control loop, it should. But it also begs the question, why all the trouble? Why not just buy a commercial switch regulator?

Comment: If my expectation does not cheat, when I modify the Duty cycle, just the current changes and the battery keeps the voltage "constant" on the output.

Comment: Voltage yes, but you need two loops, one for current or one for voltage.

Comment: If I am right to achieve CC/CV the followings are needed:
In the CC mode I just use the buck output and regulate current by varying the duty cycle.
In the CV mode I should use a voltage regulator (like LDO) on the output by turning on a switch.
I am right?

Comment: No. You are always PWMing and all control is done by varying the duty cycle. I would seriously suggest you get a ready-made regulator and "bootstrap" yourself from there. Perhaps even a working buck and make your own analog dual-loop CC/CV control in order to get acquainted with the problem.

Comment: I see
So in my current project the CC/CV is going to be a very hard duty, just charging the battery till it gets to 4.2 V.

Comment: Sorry.

I haven't seen the last sentence.
If I design a particular CC/CV loop at the output of the buck, it may help my problem.

Comment: Define "hard duty". Given same input voltage and CCM operation, your duty cycle will remain almost constant until you get to very low current at the end of the CV part. "Behind the scenes" you do however have to distinct control loops, one voltage and one current, which will both translate into a duty cycle request from the buck converter.

Comment: Excuse me. I meant difficult task.
When the state of charge is getting to end of charge, the current flowing into the battery is getting lower and lower (drops to C/10) but if the D is constant, the voltage is getting higher. Would it happen?

Comment: As long as you are in CCM, pretty much yes. Second order effects like RdsON and ESR of your choke will come into play too, but not much.

Comment: Choosing an inductor with higher inductance helps me to stay in CCM (with low ESR). Is it right?

Comment: Correct. With asynchronous rectification, you can't avoid DCM unless you stop switching at the end of CV mode, so you better prepare for it anyway. More problems which comes to mind is duty cycle resolution. Do you have 8 bits?

Comment: The resolution of the PWM timer is up-to 16 bits.
Is it safer to put an LDO with a switch (turn on at CV)?

Comment: Ay caramba! The complexity! No, you would just add problems. 16 bits should give you enough resolution and if not, you can do skip cycle at the end.

Comment: Thank you!
I am going to build the circuit soon and test it.
Is an over-current and over-voltage protection (with IC) required besides the Li-Po's inbuilt protection?

Comment: The battery will not care how you provide it so as long as your current loop is working, you should be set.